# ios push notification performance

Tags: php, performance, push-notification

This is my php push notification code for ios below:

```
<?php
// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = "********************************************";

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = "********";

function pushIOSNotification($message) 
{
   GLOBAL $deviceToken;
   GLOBAL $passphrase;

   $ctx = stream_context_create();

   $path = dirname(__FILE__).'/ck.pem';
   //echo $path;

   stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $path);
   stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

   // Open a connection to the APNS server
   $fp = stream_socket_client(
        'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
        $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

   if (!$fp)
        exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

   //echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

   // Create the payload body
   $body['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => $message,
        'sound' => 'default'
        );

   // Encode the payload as JSON
   $payload = json_encode($body);

   // Build the binary notification
   $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

   // Send it to the server
   $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

   if (!$result)
        echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
   else
        echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;



   // Close the connection to the server
   fclose($fp);
}
```

This code is only for one device,

if I need send to everyone and support localization,

this code will be like these below.

```
foreach($deviceTokens as $deviceToken){
   $deviceOS = "query this device os from  memcache";
   if($deviceOS == "ios")
   {
       $lang = "query this device langauge from  memcache";
       $message = $messageData[$lang];
       pushIOSNotification($deviceToken,$message);

   }
}
```

but I doubt this performance of this code,
because deviceTokens length is the number of all members.

Comment: `deviceTokens length is the number of all members` It means ?? You mean to say about the performance fear about `foreach` as it includes all members in your table ?

Comment: To Sulthan Allaudeen:yes, it depend on my members data from db table

Comment: If you fear about the execution time, then you shall make it a cron, so your server can be free enough. (Coz already i did that same for me)